# How do i change my dedicated memory on my dell optiplex 780?

Tags: windows-7, dell-optiplex

Hello I have been a gamer for a while now and I have noticed that I only have 64mb of dedicated memory can someone please tell me how to change it.So I can use higher qualities on stuff and have it run fluently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically dedicated memory is for your onboard video, which is typically much too weak for gaming. In many older systems, the onboard video adaptor is a seperate chip and is *always* turned off when you plug in a video card. On newer ones, you need to explicitly enable running them side by side.

As a gamer? You want this to be set to the minimum possible, no real point dedicating memory to a onboard video adaptor *you arn't using*.

That said, this is usually changed in your bios/UEFI settings.

Looking at this model/chipset its an older system, and you probably don't need to change this setting at all with a dedicated card. If it isn't, you have an older intel video adaptor, and you should consider at least a low end dedicated video card.